# IntelliSense Problem in VisualStudio code

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, ide, intellisense

i have a problem with Visual Studio Code for Mac OS

Since my small industry where i work, decided one week ago to change from Windows to Apple problems started.
I installed VS code in my Apple laptop but when i started to programming, i saw that if i make a Syntax error, the IDE doesn't highlight it (i write programs in C).

For example if i write: println("hello word") without ; VS doesn't show a red underline and a message (for example "Syntax error missing ;")

i searched on internet, and i found that is a problem of "IntelliSense" i think. I also tried some solutions, but without any result.
thanks for your answers

Answer (score 0):

Setting up VS code for C / C++ on mac is a bit of a pain. I've found [this page from MS](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp) to give a thorough run through on getting setting up, and then you can also follow [this guide](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-clang-mac) which will take you through setting up project configurations and in your case intellisense.

Comment: thanks, i tried to follow the guide, but nothing happen